# How to add echo write commands to sudoers

Tags: sudo, echo

I would like to add a command that use echo to write to files into sudoers so that it can be run without a password.

Typically the command would go like this:

```
sudo sh -c 'echo 1 > /sys/devices/system/cpu/intel_pstate/no_turbo'
```

(The sh -c is there because running echo directly on sudo just returns permission denied)

And typically to make a command runnable by sudo without password for a user it would be done by adding this to the sudoers file:

```
cestarian ALL = NOPASSWD: /bin/sh
```

However I naturally do not want sh to be executable without a password as that would be quite exploitable I imagine, I just want this specific command to work however...

```
cestarian ALL = NOPASSWD: /bin/sh -c 'echo 1 > /sys/devices/system/cpu/intel_pstate/no_turbo'
```

This does not work, I know sudoers is supposed to be able to accept commands with specific arguments, but in this case it doesn't work and I do not know why.

I'd like a way to make it work though.

Comment: @Quasimodo that's a nice alternative, I'm a bit torn between this and larsks' answer but i think i'll probably go with larsks solution of making a script for it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`sudo` does not treat `'` and `"` specially when used as arguments for a command. You can see this if you use `sudo -ll` to list what sudo has parsed. For your example it will say

```
/bin/sh -c 'echo 1 > /sys/...'
```

and it is expecting real quotes, so it would match, for example,

```
sudo sh -c "'echo 1 > /sys/...'"
```

What you can do is remove the quotes within the sudoers file and escape the spaces with backslash:

```
cestarian ALL = NOPASSWD: /bin/sh -c echo\ 1\ >\ /sys/...
```

Answer (score 3):

It looks like `sudo` is having problems with arguments that contain quotes or whitespace. There may be a syntactically correct way of dealing with this, but the simplest solution is to move the shell commands to a separate file. E.g., create `/usr/local/bin/enable_no_turbo` with the content:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo 1 > /sys/devices/system/cpu/intel_pstate/no_turbo
```

Make it executable:

```
chmod 755 /usr/local/bin/enable-no-turbo
```

And enable it in your `sudoers`:

```
cestarian ALL = NOPASSWD: /usr/local/bin/enable-no-turbo
```

---

If you wanted a more generic solution, instead create `/usr/local/bin/write-to-file` with this content:

```
#!/bin/sh

echo "$2" > "$1"
```

And in your `sudoers`:

```
cestarian ALL = NOPASSWD: /usr/local/bin/write-to-file /sys/devices/system/cpu/intel_pstate/no_turbo 1
```

This will permit:

```
sudo write-to-file /sys/devices/system/cpu/intel_pstate/no_turbo 1
```

But will not permit any of:

```
sudo write-to-file /sys/devices/system/cpu/intel_pstate/no_turbo 0
sudo write-to-file /some/other/file 1
```

Etc.

Comment: I really like this solution, and i'm gonna use it, but i'm gonna wait and see if someone doesn't know how to bend the sudoers file to obey their will enough to make it work with those args before accepting this answer.

Comment: There's a potential danger that such a `write-to-file` script could be used by mistake to overwrite a file that shouldn't be touched, such as `/dev/mem`.  I don't consider this kind of script to be safe.

Comment: @SottoVoce I'm not sure I see the risk: either you already have the permissions to do so, so you can do it without the script, or you've been explicitly granted permissions via the `sudoers` file, in which case you only have the ability to modify specific files. If you can explain more about the potential risk you envision I'd be interested.

Answer (score 2):

Alternative way is allowing `tee` such file in `sudoers`

```
username ALL = NOPASSWD: /bin/tee sys/devices/system/cpu/intel_pstate/no_turbo
```

Then using `| sudo tee` instead of `>`

```
echo 1 | sudo tee /sys/devices/system/cpu/intel_pstate/no_turbo
```

Comment: This works, although you might want to clarify your answer to be to add "username ALL = NOPASSWD: /bin/tee /sys/devices/system/cpu/intel_pstate/no_turbo" to sudoers (since adding tee by itself without args is too easily exploitable)

Comment: @Cestarian good suggestion and done.

Comment: The downside to this is that it allows you to write arbitrary content to the target file (which maybe is just fine for your use case).